# Is this method of creating bottom toolbar acceptable?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

before I proceed, I'm sorry for my bad English.. I have started with Android and I have one question for you guys.. I want to create the bottom toolbar, where an items should have equal width and should take up the whole available width of parent. I have wrote something but I don't know is this approach acceptable.

Thanks for your time

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/bottom_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:background="#11000000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/dial"
            android:src="@drawable/phone370"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/send_message"
            android:src="@drawable/sms6"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/camera59"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: yes it is very good and very great. thumbs up sir, you are very good on this

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to use any of the features in toolbar (see https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html)
You can simply use only LinearLayout.

For best result set `layout_width="0dp"` for each ImageButton...
(layout_weight doesn't work well with `layout_width="match_parent"` or `"wrap_content"`)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions